# Splunk match partial result value of field and compare results

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have 3 fields in my splunk result like message, id and docId. 
Need to group the results by id and doc id which has specific messages

```
message="successfully added" id=1234 docId =1345
message="removed someUniqueId" id=1234 docId =1345
```

I have to group based on the results by both id's which has the specific message

```
 search query | rex "message=(?<message[\S\s]*>)" | where message="successfully added"
```

which is giving result for the first search, when i tried to search for second search query which is not giving result due to the someUniqueId"

```
 search query | rex "message=(?<message[\S\s]*>)" | where match(message, "removed *")
```

Could you pelase help me to filter the results which has the 2 messages and group by id and docID

Answer (score 2):

The `match` function expects a regular expression, not a pattern, as the second argument.  Try `search query | rex "message=(?<message>[\S\s]*)" | where match(message, "removed .*")`.
BTW, the regex strings in the `rex` commands are invalid, but that may be a typing error in the question.

Comment: It is not giving any result